# Big query replace a letter in a string by position

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, legacy-sql

I would to like to replace a letter in a string by position in big query.
for example XXXXX, YYYYY, ZZZZZ the 5th letter in the string to 0
I've tried to use the Stuff function, but big query doesn't find the function
Stuff(XXXXX, 5, 1, '0')

Answer (score 2):

Probably the simplest method is more basic string operations:

```
select concat(substr(x, 1, 4), '0', substr(x, 6))
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and Legacy SQL (works for both)

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(str, r'(.{4}).(.*)', r'\10\2')
```